# Need Help Array for loop If else statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

need help with For loop array , i want the opposite data of function,
but when i try `arr[i] != elem` it print out all the array;
and if i try `arr[i] == elem` , it give me the array that i don't want;
still don't understand why it not work with `!= (not equal)`.

```
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
let newArr = [];
// change code below this line
for(let i = arr.length -1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
  for(let j = arr[i].length-1;j >= 0;j--) {
    if(arr[i][j] !== elem) {
        newArr.push(arr[i]);
     }
   }
 }
 // change code above this line
  return newArr;
}

console.log(filteredArray([ ["trumpets", 2], ["flutes", 4], ["saxophones", 2] ], 2));
```

the result i want is `["flutes", 4]`
sorry if this have been asking by others, i have been looking for the answer trough google , but can not find it.

thanks for the help

Comment: Arrays and objects are not comparable like that. Arrays already offer a built in filter function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1):

You were nearly there!

You were checking against every value in the array. I.e.: `2 !== "trumpets"` **and** `2 !== 2`. Therefore, all arrays got pushed, because all arrays had a string value that will never match.

Remove the second loop and check for the second value of the inner array explicitly:

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
let newArr = [];
// change code below this line
for(let i = arr.length -1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    if(arr[i][1] !== elem) {
        newArr.push(arr[i]);
     }
 }
 // change code above this line
  return newArr;
}

console.log(filteredArray([ ["trumpets", 2], ["flutes", 4], ["saxophones", 2] ], 2));
```

The snippet above shows the error in your current approach, but doesn't provide a very re-usable function. If you want to check whether an array *includes* a value, it's easiest to fall back to some of the built in array methods:

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  return arr.filter(values => !values.includes(elem));
}

console.log(filteredArray([ ["trumpets", 2], ["flutes", 4], ["saxophones", 2] ], 2));

console.log(filteredArray([ ["amy", "beth", "sam"], ["dave", "sean", "peter"] ], "peter"));
```

Comment: thanks for reply it don't work if my array were :
filteredArray([ ["amy", "beth", "sam"], ["dave", "sean", "peter"] ], "peter")

Comment: I tried to explain what was happening so you could decide for yourself what the best fix would be. I added an example that includes a "copy-pastable" snippet, but I'd still advice you to implement it using the `for` loop first.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  var resultArray = arr.filter(function(item) {
    return item.indexOf(elem) == -1;
  });
  return resultArray[0]
}
console.log(
  filteredArray([["trumpets", 2], ["flutes", 4], ["saxophones", 2]], 2)
);
console.log(
  filteredArray([ ["amy", "beth", "sam"], ["dave", "sean", "peter"] ], "peter")
);
```

This code snippet will return the first item in the input array which is not matching with the given second param to the function. If we need all the items which are not matching, replace `return resultArray[0]` with `return resultArray`.

Consider a case where we are calling this function with following parameter,

`filteredArray([["trumpets", 2], ["flutes", 4], ["saxophones", 5]], 2)`

`return resultArray[0]` will give `["flutes", 4]`

If we need all the items which are not matching we can do

`return resultArray` will give `[["flutes", 4], ["saxophones", 5]]`

Comment: What are you replacing `resultArray[0]` with? You have the same code as the replace...

Comment: @Matt If there is more than one item in the input array which is not matching for the given `elem` value, resultArray will have multiple items in it. In that case, we can return the whole array instead of the first element.

Comment: @Matt Updated my answer with that scenario as well

Comment: I get your scenario and I know what to replace it with, but OP may not. You say `return resultArray[0]` with `return resultArray[0]`. Make your changes in your text to display correctly.